# Restrict values of an array type

Tags: javascript, swagger, jsonschema

It cannot be easier, frankly, however I cannot find the solution anywhere.

I would like to accept an array from the front, with restricted values.

Having the following jsonschema:

```js
const models = {
  type: "string",
  enum: [
    "model1",
    "model2",
    "model3",
  ],
};

const cleanQ = {
  type: "object",
  required: ["models"],
  properties: {
    models: {
      type: "array",
      anyOf: [models],
    },
  },
  additionalProperties: false,
};
```

I can get an array input type on the front like the following:

[image]

that only accepts one single value, and in the back it is transformed as a string value. If I add another correct value, I have the following error:

> Request failed validation: Error: querystring/models must be equal to one of the allowed values, querystring/models must match a schema in anyOf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want an `items` keyword in there.

```js
const cleanQ = {
  type: "object",
  required: ["models"],
  properties: {
    models: {
      type: "array",
      items: {
        anyOf: [models]
      }
    },
  },
  additionalProperties: false,
};
```

Having `type: array` is correct to constrain your data to being an array.  However the subschemas in `anyOf` require one of the enum values.

To specify what the *items* of the array need to be, you need to use the `items` keyword.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does render by swagger and the request is well formatted as an array. However it accepts only one single correct value. If I add a second one it fails.

Comment: so I can send `['model1']` or `['model2']` but I cannot send `['model1', 'model2']`

Comment: `anyOf` is not even needed here - `items: models` should work.

Comment: actually it does not. As I said, one value is accepted , two (+) are not.

Comment: My bad, sorry; the problem was not with jsonschema definition, but with my server. Actually my client is Swagger and my parser is *qs*. All these result in a bad format of the array being processed.
So to finish with this: It does work !